# How to extend Map.Make functor

Tags: ocaml

I can write my own extension for `List` module of OCaml, by defining a file `lib.ml` and including `List` module:

```
module List =
struct
  include List

  (* remove l x returns the list l without the first element x found or *) 
  (* returns l if no element is equal to x. *)
  (* Elements are compared using ( = ). *)
  let rec remove (l : 'a list)  (x : 'a) : 'a list =
    match l with
    | [] -> []
    | hd :: tl ->
      if hd = x then
        tl else
        hd :: remove tl x

  ...
end
```

Then I can call `Lib.List.remove ...` in other files.

Now I would like to write my own extension for `Map.Make` functor, I tried something like follows in `lib.ml`:

```
module Make (Ord : Map.OrderedType with type key = Ord.t) =
struct
  include Map.Make(Ord)
  let aaa = 1
end
```

However, the compilation gives an error `Error: The signature constrained by 'with' has no component named key`.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to constraint the signature of the *argument* of your functor? You don't need any `with type` here:

```
module Make (Ord : Map.OrderedType) =
struct
  include Map.Make(Ord)
  let aaa = 1
end
```

gives you a functor `Make` that given an implementation of `Map.OrderedType` returns a module with all the functions of `Map.S`, a type `key` equal to `Ord.t`, and a value `aaa` of type `int`.

If you want to force the *result* of your functor to adhere to a certain signature, then you might indeed need to add type constraints, e.g.

```
module type MyMap = sig include Map.S val aaa: int end
module MakeAbstract (Ord : Map.OrderedType): MyMap with type key = Ord.t =
struct
  include Map.Make(Ord)
  let aaa = 1
end
```

There's one difference between `Make` and `MakeAbstract`. The former has a type `t` equal to `MapMake(Ord).t` while the latter has an abstract type `t`

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this is to follow the structure of Map.mli, with an S module followed by a Make module.

**myMap.mli**

```
module type S = sig
  include Map.S
  val keys: 'a t -> key list
end

module Make (Ord: Map.OrderedType): S with type key = Ord.t
```

you were right about the "with" constraints but you put it in the wrong position.

Then, in **myMap.ml**:

```
module type S = sig
  include Map.S
  val keys: 'a t -> key list
end

module Make = functor (Ord: Map.OrderedType) -> struct
  module Map = Map.Make(Ord)
  include Map
  let keys m =
    Map.fold (fun k _ acc -> k :: acc) m []
end
```

Hope that helps!